# Snowflake NUMBER(x,7) number stored can have less decimal places: how to choose the most precise one?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rounding, number-formatting

I have a table with lat/long as NUMBER(9,7) and NUMBER(10,7) respectively.
Sometimes we store less precise coordinates, sometimes more, meaning more decimal places.
When we have similar coordinates like this:

```
ST_GEOHASH | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE
d3f71dbq87gk 10.3873367 -75.519661
d3f71dbq87gk 10.3873367 -75.5196609
dpsb7fr5gqs4 42.2444839 -83.1457596
dpsb7fr5gqs4 42.2444840 -83.1457596
```

we would like to choose just the one that has more decimal cases on LAT/LONG or max(LAT) if they both have the same amount of decimal places.
How can I achieve that if length(number) always returns the nr defined for this column's datatype?

Comment: Hi - how are you querying for these records at the moment i.e. what is the SQL that currently returns rows 1&2 or rows 3&4?

Comment: Hi, I'm just querying like normal select from a small table of coordinates, which get assigned the same ST_GEOHASH (varchar(12) in which the lat/long gets rounded to 7 decimal places. Sometimes coordinates get the same geohash, because they're very very near each other, but in that case, I want to choose the pair of coordinates with more precise decimal places or MAX(LATITUDE) or MAX(LONGITUDE) in case they're equal.